# date format | delete 00´s when year has 00 month or day

Tags: php, date, datetime

I was wondering whats the best way to delete 00 numbers when the date is absolute. I got multiple date´s in my documents. there are dates without month and day information and some with.

example:

if the value is 2016:00:00  delete the 00:00`s  = 2016
if the value is 2016:01:10 do not delete = 2016:01:10

I am using PHP 7

Comment: Do you want to delete that row from the document or just want to fetch only non-zero values from the document?

Comment: Can you add your code, what have you implemented for this?

Comment: these are my `const DATE_START_FIELDS = [ '81_datestart', '82_datumstart' ];
 const DATE_END_FIELDS = [ '81_dateend', '82_datumend' ];` the first one for date "start", the scond for date "end".  I use angular for the frontend to show the values {{doc.datestart}} - {{doc.dateend}}

Comment: I don't get you! In the question, you have mentioned 2016:00:00 and here you have mentioned the array of `const`. and both are quite different!

Comment: sorry the const DATE_START_FIELDS and DATE_END_FIELDS are reading my MySQL database and have values for example like 2014:00:00 or with month and day info 2012:01:03  (these are just random dates). If the values are 00:00 ( first example ) the output should be just the year 2014.  if the values have day and month information, the output should be 2014:01:03

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//PHP 7.0
define('DATE_START_FIELDS',["2016:00:00","2016:01:10","2017:00:00","2016:00:00","2016:02:12","2016:03:12"]);

//PHP 5.x
const DATE_END_FIELDS = ["2016:00:00","2016:01:10","2017:00:00","2016:00:00","2016:02:12","2016:03:12"];

//PHP 7.0 - function defination    
function get_dates(array $arrDate): array{
        foreach($arrDate as $date){
            list($year,$month,$day) = explode(":",$date);
            $new_dates[] = ($month != 0 && $day != 0)?$date:$year;
        }
        return $new_dates;
    }

    $start_fields = get_dates(DATE_START_FIELDS);
    $end_fields = get_dates(DATE_END_FIELDS);

    var_dump($start_fields);
    var_dump($end_fields);
```

On the base of your comment, I have created this block of code!

I hope this may be useful to you!!!